# Redirect to Web Service WebMethod from ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, redirect, wsdl

I have a website created with ASP.NET and a web service, both using FormsAuthentication (which validates the user's credentials against Active Directory - LDAP).

When I call an action method of this web service for the first time I am redirected to the site's web page that actually logs the users into the system. When I'm logged in I will be redirected to the web service (ReturnUrl), but I'm guessing something gets lost in the way, because I'm getting an InvalidOperationException (in the client), containing the .asmx definition.

This happens on the first call only, the next calls work fine (since I'm going to the right place).

What am I missing here?

How should I redirect from the web site to the web service? Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you call the web service from the web application or from the browser? If you need authentication for the call, you should ensure that the user is authenticated before you call the webservice. A web service has no user interface on the browser, therefore you cannot "redirect" to the service. I don't understand your last remark: "redirect from the web site to the web server".

Comment: It was a typo; supposed to the service. I'm using a test client, a simple call to a web method. No browser involved. I see the issue, i understand that the problem is how i'm handling my authentication but i was trying not to change it because i've added a web service to the mix!

Comment: hmmh, I still don't see what you want to do. Are web service and web site on the same domain? Does the web app call the service or your test client calls both? How do you handle the redirect to the login page by your test client?

Comment: I have IIS Web Site with an ASP.NET web site AND a Web Service, using the same authentication method. When i call any Web Service action for the first time, i am redirected to the Active Directory Auth web page. After i am successfully authenticated i would like to return to the Web Service action. And i'm not being redirected to the right place. I wanted to know how to do this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service call is doing a `Post`, then redirecting via a `Get` request after authentication.  The default response from an ASMX is the .wsdl definition.  You can't do web service authentication like this programmatically.

If you are using Active Directory, why not use Windows Authentication and suppress the login?

Comment: Oh, i figured as much. In this case, i think i'll have to change to Windows Auth - i'm using Forms because i have windows auth + user/pass as auth methods). Thanks for clearing this up for me!